# How to store the hex value generated by MD5 as an integer?

Tags: c, hex, int, md5

I am using the following code to generate the MD5 hash for a string. The value printed in hex seems to be correct (i verified it on a website for the same string). However when I print the value as an integer it has 36 digits. My understanding is that it should have 16 digits because the hash generated is 128 bits long.

I'm want to know how the conversion from the unsigned char to int should be done and how can this be stored in a variable, so that it can ultimately be printed to a file.

It'll be nice of someone can explain how the values are being stored in the unsigned char, like how many bits is it taking to represent one digit of the hex and decimal and how can i convert between them. I tried sscanf and strtol but i guess i am not using them right.

```
    int main (void)
    {
      char *str = "tell";
      u_int8_t *output; //unsigned char
      output = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
      int i = 0;
      MD5_CTX ctx;
      MD5Init(&ctx);
      MD5Update(&ctx, str, strlen(str));
      MD5Final(output, &ctx);

      while(i < 16)
        printf("%x",output[i++]);
      printf("\n");
      i = 0;
      while(i < 16)
        printf("%i",output[i++]);
      printf("\n");
    }
```

THe output here is

```
fe17ec3c451f132ef82a3a54e84a461e
254232366069311946248425884232747030
```

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0xfe17ec3c451f132ef82a3a54e84a461e

Comment: But don't try to store hex values like this one in decimal form.

Answer (score 3):

You can't store a 128-bit value in an `int` (unless `int` is at least 128 bits on your C implementation, which I confidently predict it isn't). Same goes for `long long`, the biggest standard integer type.

The decimal value you've printed is "254" (decimal for `0xfe`), followed by "23" (decimal for `0x17`), and so on. It's basically meaningless -- if you represented either `0x010001` *or* `0x0A01` like this you'd get the same string, `101`. You got 36 digits because that happens to be the total number of decimal digits in each of the 16 byte values.

The hex value you've printed is 32 characters long (4 bits per character, 32 characters, 128 bits). This is actually a bit of luck, that each byte in your digest happens to be at least `0x10`. You should print with `%02x` to include a lead 0 for small values.

If you want to represent a 128-bit value as a decimal string then you need either a bignum library or else long division. But it's fairly pointless to express MD5 checksums in decimal: when people represent them as strings they always use hex.

> It'll be nice of someone can explain how the values are being stored in the unsigned char

8 bits of the digest in each `unsigned char`, 16 unsigned chars in the array, makes 128 bits. You can't use `sscanf` or `strtol` because the value stored by `MD5Final` is not a string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I realized that with decimal i'm printing 8 bit numbers in stead of the whole number. But, why does the same method work for hex, that is printing 8 bits each gets the hex of the digest. I need the decimal value because I want to use the decimal value as a key in a hash table and also use it in some other calculations.

Comment: Hex is a representation where every 4 bits are represented by one symbol. You are conveniently getting and printing two at the same time ... It's no coincidence that hex is a popular representation for dealing with factors of 2!

Comment: What tripleee says. Any power of 2 has the same convenient property. You can take some binary data, grab `n` bits of it at a time, and print out each chunk independently as a numeral in base `2^n` (perhaps with some complications to do with endian-ness). The result is a representation of the whole binary data in base `2^n`. It doesn't work for bases that aren't powers of 2 because the first digit in base 10 doesn't depend only on the first few bits.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the decimal value of each byte (254, 23, 236, ...), not a single 128-bit value converted to an int. Your loop should look something like `value <<= 8; value+=output[i++]` (provided your `value` is a type which can accommodate such a big number).

Your expectancy for how many digits the result should be is also off; unless you print leading zeros, its length could be anything between 1 and len(2**128-1), which is 39 decimal digits.

By the by, you should also zero-pad your hex output, otherwise any byte with a value below 16 will print a single hex digit (`printf("%02x",...)`).

Comment: tripleee, thanks for your response. Could you let me know how `value <<= 8; value+=output[i++]` works? i know that you are left shifting the bits in value, but why add `value+output[i++]` every time? If we just say `value=output[i++]` wouldn't the bits of output[i] fill the least significant bit spaces of value and then we just left shift them to accommodate the next 8 bits?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The representation you get can be interpreted as a base-256 number where each byte contains one "digit" 0-255.